# What are the reasons for German Bishops who favor the "Synodal Path" for not just becoming Protestants?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, germany, synodal-path

I was reading an [interesting article](https://www.ncregister.com/blog/pastor-of-luther-s-church-synodal-path-is-the-wrong-path) on the National Catholic Register where the pastor at Martin Luther's church in Wittenburg said he thought that people who disagree with the Catholic Church and fundamentally want to change her, or democratize her, should just become Protestants instead.

Owing to the citation that Catholics are leaving the faith in droves in Germany over the [last few years](https://www.ncregister.com/cna/survey-one-in-three-catholics-in-germany-thinking-of-leaving-church) what reasons or justifications do Bishops and Cardinals give for continuing as Catholics instead of just leaving with their congregations?

Comment: I believe the recent scandals within the ranks of the clergy play a large part here.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Not saying anything, but stating that many other factors may be involved in Catholics leaving the Church.

Comment: Question back: Why does Alexander Garth not just become Catholic? 1. There are much more differences between Catholic and Protestant Church(es) than the discussed topics. Esp. the union with the pope is important and (nearly) no one wants to break with the pope in Germany. 2. Most Catholic "reformers" (esp. the bishops) are much less radical than depicted by conservatives and also in this letter.

Comment: @K-HB that's exactly what my wife said.  If he loves the Catholic Church so much, why doesn't he marry it?  No, I can't say I understand his logic other than he is a man who loves diversity so much he wants it to remain divisive.

Comment: Synodality is not a Protestant phenomenon, it is a Catholic, and more properly, an Orthodox, phenomenon.  The fundamental change occurred when synods ceased with Vatican I.  Recall that for the vast majority of the history of the Church a synod was just a different word for a council, and councils could be ecumenical or local.

Comment: Didn't Henry VIII think he was the true Church? Did Luther call himself Protestant? I'm sure all schismatics/heretics think they're orthodox.

Comment: @Geremia: The Orthodox certainly deem themselves orthodox, hence the name; speaking of which, the Orthodox church is notoriously synodal; also, non-Protestant; in conclusion, being synodal, and being Protestant, are two distinct concepts; indeed, the [Gallicans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallicanism) were certainly not Protestant either.